# Getting dyanmic list of months starting from current month till end of yr

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get a list of the month starting from the current month. Following is my code but it doesn't populate

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-shamir-66yvf?file=/src/App.vue) is working example of my code

```
    const baseMonth = moment().month();
    //run for for loop and set the first month to current month onwards
    for (let i = 7; i < 12; i++) {
      //console.log(baseMonth[i])
      //auto select the base month in formar of MMM

      this.months = [];
      console.log(i);
      this.months.push(
        moment()
          .set("months", baseMonth[i])
          .format("MMM")
      );
    }
```

I have added comments of what I also tried. I do not understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "_it doesn't populate_" the array? You're redefining the array on every round of the loop, place `this.months = []` before the loop.

Comment: OMG. I couldn't believe I was doing that. thank u so much. How can I replace initial month and last month with static numbers like in my loop? can u also put it as answer

Comment: ?? You already have static numbers in the code. Probably you need `let i = baseMonth` instead of `7`.